# Win Server 2003: missig 'Audit' tab in advanced security propperties

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller

I am trying to set auditing on a specific file located in a share on a the server.
The server is a DC (Win 2003).
I enabled Auditing via the Domain Controller Security Policy, and I run GPUPDATE.
When I try to set the audit on the file I open Security > Advanced but there is no Auditing tab.

What can possibly cause this?

Comment: Ideas anyone???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the user under which I was trying to set auditing does not have the permission. I checked the effective permissions.